# does hoek (hapijs) transform() handle arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, hapi.js

Following the [`transform()`](https://github.com/hapijs/hoek#transformobj-transform-options) example on the [Hoek](https://github.com/hapijs/hoek) documentation, is there a way to transform arrays in the source object?

turning the example into something with an array, like this:

```
var source = {
    address: [
    {
        one: '123 main street',
        two: 'PO Box 1234'
    },
    {
        one: '456 fake street',
        two: 'Apt 2b'
    }],
    title: 'Warehouse',
    state: 'CA'
};

var result = Hoek.transform(source, {
    'person.address.lineOne': 'address.one',
    'person.address.lineTwo': 'address.two',
    'title': 'title',
    'person.address.region': 'state'
});
```

results in:

```
{
    person: {
        address: {
            lineOne: undefined,
            lineTwo: undefined,
            region: 'CA'
        }
    },
    title: 'Warehouse'
}
```

**EDIT:** adding expected results:

```
{
    person: {
        address: [{
            lineOne: '123 main street',
            lineTwo: 'PO Box 1234',
            region: 'CA'
        },
        {
            lineOne: '465 fake street',
            lineTwo: 'Apt 2b',
            region: 'CA'
        }]
    },
    title: 'Warehouse'
}
```

i presume what i'm trying to accomplish is outside of the scope of this method, but i want to be sure it's not user error here.

and if it is outside of the scope of hoek's transform, any suggestions on a good way to map a JS object to a new object, having new key names?

Comment: How do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: @GergoErdosi, great question...updated question with this edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer by @Gergo supplied is no longer the case.  On the master branch, Hoek.transform is accepting arrays and iterating over them, transforming each set of underlying keys.

Here's the related PR:
https://github.com/hapijs/hoek/pull/148

And the master branch's ReadMe (this is slated for an as of yet unreleased tag , `v2.15.0`):
https://github.com/hapijs/hoek/tree/master#transformobj-transform-options

> Transforms an existing object into a new one based on the supplied obj and transform map. options are the same as the reach options. The first argument can also be an array of objects. In that case the method will return an array of transformed objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Hoek. Hoek uses a one-to-one mapping, it can't transform arrays that way. [`Hoek.transform()`](https://github.com/hapijs/hoek#transformobj-transform-options) iterates through the keys of the map. It gets the value from the source object using [`Hoek.reach()`](https://github.com/hapijs/hoek#reachobj-chain-options) and assign it to the new object:

```
var keys = Object.keys(transform);

for (var k = 0, kl = keys.length; k < kl; ++k) {
    ...
    res[segment] = exports.reach(source, sourcePath, options);
}
```

See the [source code](https://github.com/hapijs/hoek/blob/master/lib/index.js#L822-L851) for more details. If this is all you need to do, you can easily use just pure JavaScript:

```
var result = {
    title: source.title,
    address: []
};

source.address.forEach(function(address) {

    result.address.push({
        lineOne: address.one,
        lineTwo: address.two,
        region: source.state
    });
});
```